# How to purchase ETH at one of the top ETH exchanges (for Singapore residents)?

Tags: exchanges

I'm based in Singapore and would like to know the options I have for buying Ethereum.

We don't have a local ETH exchange, but there's a BTC exchange called FYBSG. I suppose I can do Singapore Dollar to BTC conversion on FYBSG, transfer the BTC to Poloniux etc and convert to ETH there, but it seems inefficient and costly.

Any other ways to purchase ETH at one of the top ETH exchanges when you are a Singapore resident?

Comment: If it's easy to buy BTC, you should go for it.

Comment: You can try https://localbitcoins.com/country/SG, then convert your bitcoins using shapeshift.io or one of the may exchanges supporting BTC->ETH - see https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/#markets.